# window message Event firing more than one time sometime

Tags: javascript, message

I have an IFrame in my page. I'm using postmessage to establish a communication between the script of parent page and child page. I also have a polar to reflect the Iframe minimize and maximize state in all tab using cookie.

But the problem is that I've a counter which will actually increase when my child page send a message with special object. But the message event fires in the parent page more than one times. If it fires more than one time the counter will be wrong. This is not happening consistently. Sometimes it working perfectly and sometime not. Does it have any relation with the polar?  Because when I comment this everything working fine.

Here this the listener

```
function listenIframe() {
    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];       

    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    // Listen to message from child IFrame window
    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        if (e.data == xyz) {
            close();
        } else if (e.data == abcd) {
           //increase Count;
        }
    }, false);
}
```

Here is the poller

```
function fn(start) {
    var x, y, z;

    if (start) {
        j.k= setTimeout(function stateChangePollar() {
            // show or hide logic here

            setTimeout(stateChangePollar, 1000);
        }, 1000);
    }
    else {
        clearTimeout(j.k);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When is your `listenIframe` called? Can it be that it's called multiple times? The best way would be to ensure that it only gets called once, otherwise one solution would be to store something in an outside variable to check it, like this:

```
let isListenerAttached = false;

function listenIframe() {
    if (isListenerAttached) return;
    isListenerAttached = true;

    var eventMethod = window.addEventListener ? "addEventListener" : "attachEvent";
    var eventer = window[eventMethod];       

    var messageEvent = eventMethod == "attachEvent" ? "onmessage" : "message";

    // Listen to message from child IFrame window
    eventer(messageEvent, function (e) {
        if (e.data == xyz) {
            close();
        } else if (e.data == abcd) {
           //increase Count;
        }
    }, false);
}
```

This is not an optimal solution though, it can easily get messy by handling this with outside variables. Especially if it'll be a global variable. The best solution would be to ensure that `listenIframe` is only called once.

Comment: Yes listenIframe is called only once. I'm sure about it. And all the methods and variable are namespaced.
Even if I attached debugger in any place then also the message event fires more than 5 times.

Comment: If you put a `console.log` inside the fn that dispatches the message event in the iframe, can you see if it's dispatches multiple times?

Comment: Yes I checked this using debugger.

Answer (score 6):

This is probably due to having `addEventListener` called more than once, most likely in a loop or in a different file.

In fact, every time you invoke the `addEventListener` method, a new handler function is attached to the event stack, and executed when the event is fired.

Say you are interested in the `resize` event of the `window` object:

```js
function resizeHandler(e) {
   console.log("Window is resized");
}

window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
window.addEventListener("resize", resizeHandler);
```

If the window is now resized, in console you'll have:

```sh
Window is resized
Window is resized
```

So, at first it may seem that the event is called multiple times, whereas the truth is that the event is called only once, but multiple handlers are listening to that event.

You can solve this problem by being sure that in your code you have **only one** `addEventListener` for that particular event.

Comment: What is the solution then? you only told us why, but what is the solution ?

Comment: @NicholasMberev I have extended my answer with additional details, hopefully you'll find it clearer.